# 1 Stationary time series, 1 non stationary: do I need to transform BOTH, OR can I use VAR with 1 transformed and 1 stationary variable?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, data-transformation, stationarity, vector-autoregression

I am doing a time series forecast using VAR. I have 2 time series, "orders" and "calls"

The orders time series is stationary
The calls time series is non-stationary

Let's say I use the transformation method and use log to make the "calls" time series stationary.

Do I need to also transform the other series (orders) even though it is already stationary to fit the VAR model ? Can I make forecast predictions with VAR using 1 non transformed and 1 transformed variable ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not have to transform the series that is already stationary. You can use one series transformed and the other not transformed.

Yes, you can build a VAR model for them and make forecasts.